# csv file with multiple columns to zenity

Tags: bash, csv, zenity

How could I output the contents of a .csv file to a Zenity list. The file has multiple rows and columns and the rows are no fixed numbers. I would also like it so that when the user double clicks, on one of the entries it open a Zenity form with the text field filled in so that the csv file can be update I am using a shell bash file.

I have tried by googling but have not had much luck if you can help with just part of this then please post a answer.

Comment: You should describe (no example) your input data more clearly. Is this full fledged [tag:csv] or the [tag:csv-simple] that has no newlines, separator characters or quotes in its fields?

Answer (score 1):

Input csv

$> cat data.csv

```
Mumbai,India
Chicago,USA
London,UK
New York,USA
```

Format CSV Output. Add line number split each column value with new line.

```
cat data.csv | \
awk -F ',' '{
    print NR; # Print Record Number 
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        print $i; # Print Each Column separeted by Default EOL
    }
}' | \
zenity --list \
--title="Title" \
--column="Index" --column="City" --column="Country" \
--print-column=2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat lang.txt 
Brazil,Brasilia,Portugues
England,London,English
France,Paris,French
Germany,Berlim,German
$ zenity --list --title Foolish \
    --column Contry --column Capitol --column Language \
    --print-column=2 $(tr , \\n < lang.txt)
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.